# How many people use public transit in the U.S.?

Tags: public-transport

To answer [a question on Sustainability.SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/10208/3379), I am interested in finding data on how many people in the U.S. utilize public transit in a given year.

Most of the data I can find in the [National Transit Data](https://www.transit.dot.gov/ntd/ntd-data) covers *ridership*, defined as rides taken during a time period. So if the period is one year and a person takes the bus twice a week, that counts as 104 rides. I want to know how many unique individuals use any form of public transit in a given year. A reasonable approximation with a defined methodology would be sufficient.